# Node.js require() code completion in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

In Node.js and WebStorm, we want to avoid using `require()` with relative file paths, e.g.
`require('../../../../../ugly/path/to/file')`

We've tried using the include function from here:
https://coderwall.com/p/th6ssq/absolute-paths-require

```
global.base_dir = __dirname;
global.abs_path = function(path) {
  return base_dir + path;
}
global.include = function(file) {
  return require(abs_path('/' + file));
}
```

`global.include` is basically require(), but uses an absolute path, eliminating the need for all the `../../../.`

The problem is that WebStorm method hinting and autocompletion doesn't work with this. So is there any workaround that allows for WebStorm method completion AND absolute require() paths?